# Disable HDMI output from QtQuick2 Application on embedded Linux

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, yocto, eglfs

I've got an embeddedLinux board with a Qt5 Application. The goal is to disable the display when unused or currently not needed.

I use EGLFS and the display is connected to HDMI. Echo 1 to /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank has no impact but is also not complaining.

Hiding the QtQuickView has no impact. Set visibility to false neither.

Embedded Linux is build using yocto.

No problems with the build so far. My only problem left: Disable the HDMI out if not needed.

Any ideas what to try?

BR

ML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is a proper approach, at least it works:

to turn off:

```
echo off > /sys/class/drm/cardX/connectorY/status
```

ro recover:

```
echo on > /sys/class/drm/cardX/connectorY/status
```

from command line

and from Qt via a QFile operation.

Maybe it will help someone else. Better approaches are of course still welcome.